# Parallel Matrix Multiplication

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I wrote a simple  parallel matrix multiplication using `par` and `pseq`.

After running this program, none of the sparks converted (SPARKS: 20 (0 converted, 0 pruned)).

I would like to hear your comment about improving this program.

Also about approaches for learning parallel programming in Haskell.

```
import Data.List
import Control.Parallel

parHelp :: ( Num a ) => [ a ] -> [ a ] -> a 
parHelp [] [] = 0
parHelp ( x : xs ) ( y : ys ) = ret where 
ret = par a ( pseq b ( a + b ) ) where 
        a = x * y 
        b = parHelp xs ys

helpMult :: ( Num a ) => [ a ] -> [ [ a ] ] -> [ a ]
helpMult _ [] = [] 
helpMult x ( y : ys ) = ret where 
 ret =  par a ( pseq b  ( a : b ) ) where 
   a = sum . zipWith ( *) x $ y  
   b = helpMult x ys

mult :: ( Num a ) => [ [ a ] ] -> [ [ a ] ] -> [ [ a ] ]
mult [] _ = []  
mult ( x : xs ) ys = ret where 
 ret = par a ( pseq b  ( a : b ) ) where 
    a = helpMult x ys 
    b = mult xs ys

main = print $ mult [[1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4] ] ( transpose [[1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4 ] , [ 1 .. 4] ])
```

Comment: OT. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: A list of lists is not a matrix.  I suggest you learn and use Repa for this purpose.  If you want to learn how to use the parallel package, I encourage you to select another application domain and re-ask the question.

Comment: Disagree with the close vote; SO could use more content on parallel Haskell.

Comment: Does this code actually *work* (give you the expected results), and you just want to improve the performance and/or parallelize it, or does this code *not work* (not give you the expected results) and you are looking to understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: @casperOne As I mentioned I am learning parallel programming and in Simon Peyton Jones and Satnam Singh  paper , it is mentioned that to get the parallel speed , sparks should be converted and my none of sparks converted so I asked here. Clearly my test data was not strong enough ( as mentioned by nponeccop ) to test the parallelism. I will test with 1000X1000 matrix and put the result.

Comment: @keep_learning: Let me be more clear, are you looking to optimize this code, or not?  Right now, in it's current form, does it give the output that you expect?

Comment: @casperOne Sorry if i sound disrespectful. Yes its giving the correct result so its working fine. The only concern is sparks are not getting converted. I would love to here your suggestion and improvement to optimize this code.

Comment: @keep_learning: It wasn't disrespectful, I just wasn't clear on your answer.  That said, if it's working correctly and it's an optimization then it belongs on the code review site.  I'm going to migrate this in five minutes (clearing these comments first) and you can find the link on the new site then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try very large (at least 1000x1000) matrices? It is possible that the computation is too short to paralellize.

Comment: Isn't multiplication Memory Bound? I tried Intel IPP Single vs. Multi Threaded for Image Multiplication and saw no gains on AVX enabled CPU.